# Timed filter transistion animations

Tags: jquery, html, css

im working on this project where i have three posters (images) in a row.

I was wondering if it was possible to set a timed animation to each poster that loops.

as in all but the first poster are greyscaled, for 2s, then all but the middle is greyscaled for 2s, and then the first two greyscaled for 2s.

i hope that somewhat makes sense.

thanks

Comment: `i hope that somewhat makes sense.` Nope. Please read [ask] and make sure you include a [mcve]

Comment: Google some tutorials on css transitions

Answer (score 2):

You can use `setInterval(function, time);` to let javascript repeat a function indefinitely. Alternatively you can use `setTimeout`, which will only execute once, but can be called in the function itself again. (Useful if you want some stop-condition)

In that function all you have to do then is cycle through all images. I did that using an array, but you should also be able to use `$('img')`, which selects all images and then use `<any jQuery element>.get()` to access those elements.

Then use `removeClass` and `addClass` to add and remove an CSS class, which describes your wanted effect.

Int the end you should end up with [something like this](https://codepen.io/SourceOverflow/pen/qPjKEm)

(same code from the codepen here:)

```js
var images = [$('#img1'), $('#img2'), $('#img3')];
var currImage = 0;

function cycle() {
  images[currImage].removeClass('highlighted');
  ++currImage;
  if(currImage >= images.length)
    currImage = 0;
  images[currImage].addClass('highlighted');
}

setInterval(cycle, 2000);
```

```css
img.highlighted {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="http://www.placecage.com/100/100" alt="" id="img1" class="highlighted">
  <img src="http://www.placecage.com/100/100" alt="" id="img2">
  <img src="http://www.placecage.com/100/100" alt="" id="img3">
</div>
```

---

If you also want animation, you can either do that with jQuery or by adding something along the lines of

```
img {
  transition: all 1s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

There are a lot of pages about css transitions if you want something fancier.

Comment: What does that do? How does it answer the question? Don't just blurt out code. Explain yourself! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Hmm I don't think that code is too complicated, but I guess I will improve my answer

Comment: Good example, but I think it's actually doing the opposite of what he was asking.

Comment: Oh right, he said "all but", but the concept is the same, so I won't edit it again. I'm confident, he can do the rest by himself